# Is there any possibility to use more than one NSCharacterSet Object for the same NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nscharacterset

Consider this code:

```
NSString *aString = @"\tThis is a sample string";
NSString *trimmedString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"The trimmed string: %@",trimmedString);
trimmedString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"string"]];
NSLog(@"The trimmed string: %@",trimmedString);
```

Here if I use `characterSetWithCharactersInString:` on the same `NSString` object `trimmedString`, my previous `whitespace` trimming effect gets removed..

My question is,

Is there any possibility to use more than one `NSCharacterSet` object to the same `NSString`???
or Suggest me some other way to do this please, but the `NSString` object should be one and the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not because of character sets. Its because you are using `aString` while trimming the string second time. You should use `trimmedString` instead. Your code should look like,

```
trimmedString = [trimmedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"string"]];
```

Comment: @EmptyStack: Yeah right.. I replaced 'aString' with 'trimmedString' in the second line.. Its working..   Thank u..

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
NSString *aString = @"\tThis is a sample string";
NSMutableCharacterSet *customSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
[customSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
[customSet addCharactersInString:@"string"];
NSString *trimmedString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:customSet];
[customSet release];
```

Comment: Nice Nekto.. But wat EmptyStack told is more simple..  Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I only asked your question `Is there any possibility to use more than one NSCharacterSet object to the same NSString???`. I didn't search for errors in your code =)

Comment: +1, He should prefer this method. This will be really helpful when there are more character sets he needs to use.